# Python: How do I check the encoding of a string and insert a space where it is different?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, ascii

How do I loop through a string and insert a space whenever I see a difference in encoding? For example, the input:

`Bar bar black sheep就是其中 famous 的一家club`

Should yield this output:

`Bar bar black sheep 就是其中 famous 的一家 club`

I have tried the following but is there a simpler way of doing the following?

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
sentence = 'Bar bar black sheep就是其中 famous 的一家club'

currIsAscii = None
prevIsAscii = None
newsentence = ""

for i in sentence:
  try:
    i.decode('ascii')
    currIsAscii = True
  except:
    currIsAscii = False
  if prevIsAscii != currIsAscii:
    newsentence+=" "
    newsentence+=i
  else:
    newsentence+=i
  prevIsAscii = currIsAscii

  while "  " in newsentence:
    newsentence = newsentence.replace("  ", " ")

print newsentence.strip()
```

Comment: Your string doesn't actually have a difference of encoding. It's all the same encoding, UTF-8. I think what you really want is to detect a change in unicode block, or plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://youtu.be/sgHbC6udIqc) is a pretty decent pycon talk by Ned Batchelder about all this encoding goodness, it was informative to me and I expect it will be to you too.